# How to align floated elements to the bottom of their container

Tags: html, css, css-float

Simple question, but I'm struggling with solution.

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LKmzF/).

How can I get the title and date to both align to the bottom of the container, while ensuring that:

- The length of the title will push the date across (but doesn't need to wrap)
- The blue button is always centrally aligned between the date and the red icon
- The titleBar container is always the same fixed height
- Need a CSS-only solution if possible - I already know how to do this with JS if needed

HTML:

```
div class="titlebar bgEarth0">
    <h1 id="title">Test Title</h1>
    <h2 id="date">23 October 2013</h2>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="buttonArea">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.titlebar { height: 50px; border:1px solid #000}
#title {font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; float: left;  margin:0}
#date { font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; float: left; margin-left: 30px;  margin:0 12px}
.buttonArea {position:relative; overflow:auto; height:40px; margin-top:5px}
.button {margin:0 auto; width:60px; height:40px; background:#0000ff}
.icon {float:right; background:#ff0000; height:40px; width:60px; margin-top:5px}
```

Comment: Could you post an image of what it would look like

Comment: You mean just by using `margin-top:[number]px;` or something more advanced than that? You can use `padding-top: [number]px;` and `padding-bottom: [number]px;` if you wish to make the date element as big as the title element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hC236/

You can use absolute position. 
Wrap title and date with a div and set its position to absolute.

HTML:

```
<div class="titlebar bgEarth0">
    <div class="bleh">
         <h1 id="title">Test Title</h1>
         <h2 id="date">23 October 2013</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">ddd</div>
    <div class="buttonArea">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.titlebar {
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.bleh {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    margin:0
}
#date {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin:0 12px
}

.buttonArea {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    height:40px;
    top:5px;
    right: 0px;
}

.button {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:60px;
    height:40px;
    background:#0000ff
}

.icon {
    background:#ff0000;
    height:40px;
    width:60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

**OR Table Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hjM56/

HTML:

```
<div class="titlebar">
  <div class="col-1">
    <h1 id="title">Test Title</h1>
    <h2 id="date">23 October 2013</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.titlebar {


display: table;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;

}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3 { display: table-cell; }

.col-1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 1%;
}

.col-2 {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}

.col-3 {
    text-align: right;
    width: 1%;
}

#title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#date {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

.button {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #0000ff;
    margin-top: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
    background: #ff0000;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't satisfy the first 2 of my requirements in the bulleted list?The length of the title will push the date across (but doesn't need to wrap)
The blue button is always centrally aligned between the date and the red icon

Comment: Ok so why don't you use display as table and play around with it? Do you want me to give you an example?

Comment: That's it!  Great, thanks.  You have the red/blue objects the wrong way round in your fiddle, but easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it but it involves some extra mark-up.

I added some wrappers around the title and date as follows:

```
<div class="titlebar">
    <div id="titleArea">
        <div id="table-wrap">
        <div id="table-cell">
             <h1 id="title">Test Title</h1>
             <h2 id="date">23 October 2013</h2>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="buttonArea">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Apply the following CSS:

```css
.titlebar {
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid #000
}
#titleArea {
    height:40px;
    margin-top:5px;
    float: left;
}
#table-wrap {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
#table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;    
}
#title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding:0;
    display: inline;
}
#date {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 12px;
    display: inline;
}
.buttonArea {
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.button {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:60px;
    height:40px;
    background:#0000ff
}
.icon {
    float:right;
    background:#ff0000;
    height:40px;
    width:60px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border: 1px dotted blue; /* for demo only */
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5NDDQ/

I created an outer wrapper `#titleArea` that has the same height and top margin as the `#buttonArea`.

Within `#titleArea`, I created a CSS table/table-cell (two nested div's) so that I can get the vertical alignment to be at the bottom.

Finally, I set `display: inline` to `#title` and `#date`.

A detail that may need adjustment involves the base line of the title and time. The bottom leading causes the text to sit slightly above the bottom edge of the button.

It seems like a lot of work for what appears to be a relatively simple requirement.

To make this a bit more bullet-proof, I would add a min-width to the `.titlebar` to prevent the `.buttonArea` to develop a horizontal scroll bar and the `.icon` from wrapping to a second line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it definitely does the job, but you're right it seems like a lot of markup.  I've chosen Gustonez' answer, just because it achieves the same end result with less markup.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use floating unless necessary. See this JSFiddle [<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/LKmzF/38/)

Basically if you remove the floats and `display:inline-block;` instead, they will align. I also removed the `overflow:auto`, as that would limit the icon area.

Also, adding `left:15%;` will align the blue area between the date and the red area.

**EDIT:** Example with max-width specifications to contain the div inside the title bar. [<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/LKmzF/40/)

Comment: Hi - thanks.  This is really close, but it prevents the blue button from being centrally aligned.  How can I adjust your solution so that the blue button is centrally positioned in the space between the date and the red icon?

Comment: But that only works if the title's length is always the same as 'Test Title'?  If it's any longer (or shorter), the blue button will be off-center?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the way you have your HTML set up, it won't allow for dynamic positioning like that. You can set your title and date to have a max-width and control them that way, but otherwise I don't see a way around that.